# System.Reactive: Implement an IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need to create a custom `IObservable`. I've read a bit over there, I've ended up I shouldn't implement `IObservable<T>` directly.

I've noticed that there is an `ObservableBase<T>`. This is an abstract class, so I need to implement the abstract method:

```
public class Store<TState> : ObservableBase<TState>, IObserver<IAction>
{
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnNext(IAction value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override IDisposable SubscribeCore(IObserver<TState> observer)
    {
        >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>******<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How should I implement this method?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your problem, but if you can replace implementing `IObservable` for exposing a property/method that returns `IObservable` you'll be a lot better off. If you can do that, you can easily return an Rx-based Observable from some of [Rx's create methods](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#CreationOfObservables).

If you can't do that, I would recommend wrapping a `Subject<T>`:

```
public class MyIntObservable : IObservable<int>
{
    private readonly Subject<int> _mySubject = new Subject<int>();

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
    {
        return _mySubject.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try to explain a bit deeply what I'm trying to get... There's an implementation of Redux "pattern" using angular called ngrx. This library provides a very elegant Redux implementation in my taste, so I'm trying to "translate/port" it into C#. The main class I want to translate is [Store](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/master/src/store.ts) right now. You can dismiss `lift`, `replaceReducer` and other ones to pay attention on `next`, `completed`, ... Any ideas about everything we have commented?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you entirely, and I'm not sure how that relates to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you don't want to be doing what you are doing.

From a brief look at the "Store" class that you want to mimic, it appears to be some sort of `Subject`. A `Subject` is both an `IObserver` and an `IObservable` and there are many implementations that are provided out of the box. Here is the interface:

```
public interface ISubject<in TSource, out TResult> : IObserver<TSource>, IObservable<TResult>
{
}
```

This is a very good article about `Subject`s and when to use them here:
https://www.davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx